# Can we create a temp text file with JavaScript to upload to a cloud storage?

Tags: javascript, php, kineticjs

I'm working an HTML5+JavaScript application (using KineticJS 4.4.3) that requires a save functionality

The current demo has save feature which saves the Stage to **localStorage** using `toJSON()` and is working fine.

Now I'd like to save this JSON string in a file on a cloud storage like Dropbox, Google Drive, etc. Unlike saving canvas to an image with `toDataURL()`, I'm unaware of any method in JavaScript that can create a temporary text file that I can provide a URL and upload. Any ideas?

One alternative I have in mind is using a server side function i.e. php to create a file and so on... but that will require periodic cleaning of the folder used to generate this text file (I'm using a shared hosting so not thinking of using the temp directory).

Comment: Do it on the server, JS doesn't have access to the file system

Comment: hmm... I thought so, just wanted to make sure since there was a way to create images from canvas. Any suggestions for a way to automatically delete the created file using php?

Comment: why do you need a temp file, you can just send the string var from the toDataURL() to your hosting, no need to save it locally at all...

Comment: I need a temp file that can be uploaded to the cloud storage, so yes, with server side interface I only need to send a string, generate file on server and provide the link. But my intention was to do this file+url on client side itself

Comment: I haven’t tried it, but it looks like Google Drive’s API will let you upload canvas.toDataURL(“image/jpeg”) using a POST.  You must specify your Google Drive authorization token (no anonymous POSTs allowed).  Check here:  https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

Comment: @markE I want to upload a JSON string into a file and then be able to read it back... and not an image :)

Comment: You can use Google Drive's API and specify a JSON mime-type: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8  https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads